# logable behavior - cakephp

Tags: cakephp, logging

I am trying to setup the logable behavour (link below) but I cannot seem to work out where the $activeUser line goes in the scheme of things.

I have tried within the AppController and the UserModel but each time I get this error (or similar):

Undefined property: UsersController::$activeUser [APP/
app_controller.php, line 20]

Any ideas?

Thankyou

LINK: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2008/10/21/logablebehavior

Comment: It ended up being a simple issue. 

My code when the above issue was happening:
if (sizeof($this->uses) && $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Logable')) {
$this->{$this->modelClass}->setUserData($this->activeUser());
   } 

AND NOW THE WORKING CODE:

if (sizeof($this->uses) && $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Logable')) {
$this->{$this->modelClass}->setUserData($this->Auth->user());
}   

Just had to add in $this->Auth->user() into the activeUser area and all is fine.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a simple issue. My code when the above issue was happening:

```
 if (sizeof($this->uses) && $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Logable')) { $this->{$this->modelClass}->setUserData($this->activeUser()); }
```

AND NOW THE WORKING CODE:

```
if (sizeof($this->uses) && $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Logable')) { $this->{$this->modelClass}->setUserData($this->Auth->user()); }
```

Just had to add in $this->Auth->user() into the activeUser area and all is fine. Thankyou